# Convert js Menu to VueJS (Header)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, header, vue-component

I have a one page website which i am trying to convert to VueJs. In this website i have Header component with some kind of a menu and dropdown menu with multiple choices.

This is the HTML:

```
<header class="header">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-8 d-flex flex-center">
                        <div class="logo">
                            <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-4">
                        <div class="menu-toggle">
                            <span></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="main-menu">
                            <div class="nav-menu text-right">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https:">About us</a></li>
                                    <li class="menu-dropdwon">
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0)">Products</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#management">Management</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
```

This is the js:

```
/*----- Menu Toggle Start ----- */
        $(".menu-toggle").on("click", function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("active");
            $(".main-menu").slideToggle();
            $(".nav-menu > ul ul").slideUp(200);
            $("li.menu-dropdwon a").removeClass("active");
        });
        /*----- Menu Toggle End ----- */

        /*----- Submenu Drop Down Start ----- */
        $("li.menu-dropdwon a").on("click", function() {
            if ( $(window).width() < 1025 ){
                if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
                    $(this).removeClass("active");
                    $(this).siblings(".nav-menu > ul ul").slideUp(200);
                } else {
                    $("li.menu-dropdwon a").removeClass("active");
                    $(this).addClass("active");
                    $(".menu-in").slideUp(200);
                    $(this).siblings(".nav-menu > ul ul").slideDown(200);
                };
            };
        });
        /*----- Submenu Drop Down End ----- */
```

Basically i need to convert this to VueJS component but i am not sure how.

Comment: Hi, what have you tried already? Got any specific issues?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a part of the solution, you can implement the second method `handleSubMenuClick`.

Note that you must install [vue-slide-toggle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-slide-toggle)

```
<template>
      <div>
        <div
          @click="handleClickMenu"
          :class="{ active: isActive }"
          class="menu-toggle"
        >
          <span>Menu</span>
        </div>
        <SlideToggle :open="isActive">
          <div class="main-menu">
            <div class="nav-menu text-right">
              <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="https:">About us</a></li>
                <li class="menu-dropdwon">
                  <a href="javascript:void(0)">Products</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#management">Management</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </SlideToggle>
      </div>
    </template>
        
        <script>
    import { VueSlideToggle } from "vue-slide-toggle";
    
    export default {
      name: "Menu",
      components: {
        SlideToggle: VueSlideToggle,
      },
      data() {
        return {
          isActive: false,
        };
      },
      methods: {
        handleClickMenu() {
          this.isActive = !this.isActive;
          const element = this.$el.querySelector("li.menu-dropdwon a");
    
          if (element) {
            element.classList.remove("active");
          }
        },
      },
    };
    </script>
```

Comment: Not sure where this code is coming from, but I will not recommend that one. On top of installing an NPM package that wasn't updated for 4 years, could easily be a omitted and done manually IMO.